# Grouping child objects in WPF TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I am trying to get my tree view to group a collection of similar items by what they are. To keep things generic, my object hierarchy could look like this:

- Objects

  - Object Group #1

    - Item #1 (Type 'A')
    - Item #2 (Type 'A')
    - Item #3 (Type 'B')
    - Item #4 (Type 'B')

Right now my TreeView shows these objects exactly like the object model, but what I would like to do is insert a TreeView node for each object type so that it would look like this:

- Objects

  - Object Group #1

    - Type A

      - Item #1
      - Item #2
    - Type B

      - Item #3
      - Item #4

I saw in a similar question here that someone recommended to have two separate `HierarchicalDataTemplates` so I created one for 'Object Group #1' level which contains a TreeView with a list of the types, but this is really clumsy since it is a whole separate TreeView inside of some nodes. I have also been trying to use a `CollectionViewSource` to filter out the items in each category, but this doesn't do me very much good since I can't figure out how to display them.

I guess my question boils down to this: How do I make a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` group it's children? If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it a lot.

I can post some code if anyone wants to see, but I am really just trying to figure out how to do what I want so my code is just a pretty straight forward databound treeview right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36451/Organizing-Heterogeneous-Data-on-a-WPF-TreeView.aspx) article by Mr. Sumi. I'm sure it will help you.

The gist of the article:

> My solution to that very problem requires the following ingredients:
>
> - A MultiBinding that allows you to combine different bindings.
> - A converter that helps us organizing the different bound collections
>   into sub folders, where necessary.
> - And of course: Data templates that provide a visual representation of your bound data.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this effect by binding the `ItemsSource` on your `HierarchicalDataTempalate` using an `IValueConverter`.  This converter is simply does the following:

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, ...)
  {
    return
      from item in (IEnumerable<MyItem>)value
      group item by item.Type into g
      select new { Type = g.Key, Items = g }
  }
  ...
}
```

Now your `HierarchcialDataTemplate` can be as follows:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SomePath, Converter={x:Static local:MyConverter}">

  <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate
      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
      TargetType="{x:Type local:MyItem}"

      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemTemplate}">
         <!-- may omit ItemTemplate in prior line to use implicit template -->

      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" /> <!-- Header for type -->

    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

  <!-- header for "Object Group #1" -->

</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: `select new { Type = item.Type, Items = g };` doesn't compile; maybe `select new { Type = g.First().Type, Items = g };`?

Comment: Would a collection view source be more appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `HierarchicalDataTemplate` can't group its children.

View should just display whatever it gets, without really digging into objects kinds / groups... Why don't you create these groups in your object model?

And the view will just get smth like:

```
public interface ITreeNode
{
    string Title;
    IList<ITreeNode> ChildNodes;  
}
```

and display it using the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a simple Grouping Method from a Flat Collection for display purpose that you are looking for maybe using a "CollectionViewSource" will be more suitable. Using LINQ could become a nightmare due to Property/Collection Change event propagation.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupedItems" Source="{Binding ItemsSource,  ElementName=My_UserControl}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Type" Converter="{StaticResource GroupingConverter}" />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Date"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="GroupDataTemplate"  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<TreeView x:Name="ItemHolder" x:FieldModifier="private"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedItems}, Path=Groups}"
... />
```